# How can I integrate toast notifications in WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf

I wanted to add toast notifications to my wpf app.

I've followed the [Send a local toast notification from desktop C# apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-desktop?tabs=classic) from Microsoft, but I'm stuck on the step 5.

I'm not sure how to make this code working:

```
// Construct the visuals of the toast (using Notifications library)
ToastContent toastContent = new ToastContentBuilder()
    .AddToastActivationInfo("action=viewConversation&conversationId=5", ToastActivationType.Foreground)
    .AddText("Hello world!")
    .GetToastContent();

// And create the toast notification
var toast = new ToastNotification(toastContent.GetXml());

// And then show it
DesktopNotificationManagerCompat.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

Also, I've added `<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0</TargetPlatformVersion>` to the .csproj, references to `Windows.Data`, `Windows.UI`.

At this point, I was getting 2 errors:

`The type 'XmlDocument' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'`

`The type 'ToastNotifier' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'`

When I add `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract` as a reference from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.18362.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\8.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd` I get the following error:

> The type 'ToastNotification' exists in both 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime' and 'Windows.UI, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'

How can I fix it?

Please note that I've also tried to use the ['ready example'](https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/desktop-toasts), but with the same results.

Comment: You link to an article on UWP, while you tag your question WPF. Is this the reason your toasts aren't working?

Comment: From the begging of the first link: `Desktop apps (including packaged MSIX apps, apps that use sparse packages to obtain package identity, and classic non-packaged Win32 apps) can send interactive toast notifications just like Windows apps.` I thought that like Windows apps refer to UWP and things like classic Win32 apps may refer to wpf. I might be wrong. Also, I'm pretty sure that it's possible to add toast notifications to wpf app in similar way.

Comment: There's a nuget package is a lot simpler to implement if you just want toast and don't care about the exact implementation. https://github.com/Federerer/Notifications.Wpf

Comment: As an another invented wheel, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61564124/12888024) some easy UI implementation for Toast messages. :)

Comment: Thanks @Andy, I'll probably end up using it. However, right now I'm looking for more direct solution like using toast from UWP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**NEW:**

There is a way of using UWP Toast Notifications in WPF app.

1. Add `<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0</TargetPlatformVersion>` to .csproj
2. If you have any package installed, click on `packages.config` file and select `Migrate packages.config to PackageReference...` (Important step - this was the thing that I was missing)
3. Now in Package Manager Console install UWP.Notifications package e.g.: `Install-Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications -Version 7.0.2` [Check version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications/)

Now, you should be able to use all uwp notification functions.

**OLD:**

As @Andy suggested in the comments there is ready NuGet package implementation: [github.com/Federerer/Notifications.Wpf](https://github.com/Federerer/Notifications.Wpf)

If you just want a simple notification without onClick events etc. you can use this solution:

1. Add `<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0</TargetPlatformVersion>` to .csproj
2. Add references to `Windows.UI` and `Windows.Data`
3. Add following usings: `using Windows.Data.Xml.Dom; using Windows.UI.Notifications;`
4. Use this code to show notification:

```
var message = "Sample message";
var xml = $"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><toast><visual><binding template=\"ToastText01\"><text id=\"1\">{message}</text></binding></visual></toast>";
var toastXml = new XmlDocument();
toastXml.LoadXml(xml);
var toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier("Sample toast").Show(toast);
```

[More info](https://www.meziantou.net/display-toast-notifications-in-a-wpf-application.htm)

Comment: Images don't show in this solution. Buttons and text show only.

Comment: You should be able to use all features of Uwp.Notifications. Can you share your code for the notification?

Comment: Note that there is no immediate UI once you run the app, it will show in the system tray. You can test it using the "Native Notification" button

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46246430/uwp-toast-works-but-images-adaptiveimage-toastgenericheroimage-toastgenerica Also, I'd suggest opening a new question (I'm not sure what might be causing this issue with images).

Comment: For .NET 5, change the target framework in the .csproj file to `net5.0-windows10.0.17763.0` or higher.

Answer (score 0):

This documentation is very well made, [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast?tabs=desktop) here.

Follow `Desktop(unpackaged)` for specific details on WPF apps.